# What does キャンセルをキャンセル mean? Why people write like this?

Tags: sentence

I wonder what does this mean.
Is this cancel? Or cancel and cancel?
I cannot understand very well......
Why people write like this? Can you tell me What is the best way to write this, or is there another way to write this?ll me Why?

---

Can you explain how you came up with this way of writing?
[image: The picture]

Comment: Do you understand what 破棄 means? I don't see two cancels in this message window, so it might just boil down to understanding the vocabulary.

Comment: If you understand English better: [image search of English equivalent](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Discard+edit+cancel+dialogue+ios&iar=images). If you're asking why not simply use "Yes / No", [this post may be helpful](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9946/) to add further rationale to the chosen answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, there is something I want you to know.
It is called "Dialogue".

### What is Dialogue?

Dialogs are user interface elements that interact with the user in writing. Of those, alerts are used to inform the user of an error or warning and ask for a subsequent action (agreement, denial, etc.). Users do not want someone else to take away their work, so be very careful about overuse of alerts
The picture which you used is kind of “Dialog”

### 『キャンセルのOK』と『キャンセルのキャンセル』

Please see this image first.
[image]

What do you think?
This alert is an example of an alert that asks the user whether or not to interrupt the work in the description, and then indicates two options for action: "Cancel" or "OK". Do you feel any discomfort when you see this?

[image]
In this context, we are asking the user if he/she is willing to continue with the process of "canceling edits". Many users who want to agree to continue would intuitively want to press "Cancel" with the same notation. However, this does not cancel the edit.

What this "Cancel" button means is "Cancel 'Cancel edits'". In other words, in order for the user to discard the edit as desired, the user should select the opposite OK button. Such a "cancel of cancel" should be avoided because it is a double negative and complicates the meaning.

---

So people changed the name of the button as follows, hoping that it would not become "Cancel of Cancel" here.
[image]
Are you no longer confused by this ......?

I find this correction to be incorrect. Yes" and "No" are not appropriate for action buttons in dialogs because the outcome is not predictable.

I would like to attack the alerts further. I would like to further attack a certain alert. In response to the comments of those around me, I have expanded the description as follows.
[image]

### Yes,, or No….???

This alert ultimately asks the user to "save the edits," and the user who wants to do so will intuitively choose "Yes. However, if the user selects "Yes," the original question "Cancel edits" will be executed, which means that the edits will not be saved, but rather destroyed. This is the worst possible outcome for the user.

Design short, logical and appropriate wording

This alert does not have an appropriate description to begin with. And the button names for the choices are wrong.

First of all, the word "cancel" is improperly used in the description in an unobtrusive manner. Cancel is a word often used in the names of negative buttons, so avoid asking questions that could be confused with it.

A common example of confusing the meaning of cancel is in the process of canceling an order in a mail order application by asking, "Do you want to cancel your order?" in the cancellation process of a mail order application.

[image]

### Avoid "to be" expressions as much as possible and use concise expressions.

In designing the wording of buttons, it is important to avoid the Japanese expression "〜する" as much as possible. Cancel", "Discard", "Delete", "Select", "Download", and "......" all have an extra "suru" and seem redundant. It depends on the context, but in most cases, the meaning can be understood even without the "〜する" form, so it is better to use short sentences.
In light of the above, this alert should be written as "Are you sure you want to cancel? can be rewritten as "Are you sure you want to cancel? can be rewritten as "Discard? The name of the consent button can then be "Discard".